# TypeError: edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Подскажите как исправить ошибку

```
File "bot.py", line 22, in on_message 
    await message.channel.edit(message)
TypeError: edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Вот код:

````
with open("bad_words.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file: # bad-words.txt contains one blacklisted phrase per line
    bad_words = [bad_word.strip().lower() for bad_word in file.readlines()]
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    message_content = message.content.strip().lower()
    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in message_content:
            #await message.channel.delete(message)
            await message.channel.edit(message)
            await message.channel.send("{}, поосторожней со словами!".format(message.author.mention))```
````

Comment: А что у вас находится в message и что ожидает на входе функция edit?

Comment: В message находится сообщение пользователя а функция edit должна заменит мат на ***

Comment: И всё же. Какой точно тип данных там? Само сообщение я смотрю находится в message.content, точно ли функция edit ожидает то, что находится в message (я так понимаю, там какая-то структура, содержащая сообщение)

Comment: Тип данных `str`.

Comment: Если у message тип str, то что тогда в message.content? Не может у строки быть поля content

Comment: В документации написано `MessageType` но я проверил через `print(type(...))` и выдало `str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придётся использовать форму подлиннее:

```py
await message.edit(content = message_content)
```

То есть надо передать сообщение через ключ `content`. Заметьте, что вы передали `message` вместо `message_content`. Неполадка получается.

Во-вторых, Discord API никак не позволит вам редактировать чужие сообщения. Надо удалять сообщение целиком.

В-третьих, если уж удалять сообщение по ключевым словам, то лучше использовать [регулярное выражение](https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/).

В-четвёртых, как же свобода слова? Есть риск потери активной аудитории, а обойти обнаружение просто с использованием разных символов :) Но это личное мнение уже.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете редактировать сообщение другого пользователя, только сообщение от бота. Если хотите сделать фильтр плохих слов, то можно удалить сообщение и отправить предупреждение. Вот минимальный пример для этого:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        if 'lol' in message.content: # Если есть слово lol в сообщении
            await message.delete() # Удаляем сообщение
            await message.channel.send('Сообщение') # Отправляем сообщение от имени бота
```

Если вы захотите отредактировать сообщение другого пользователя, то получите такую ошибку: `discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50005): Cannot edit a message authored by another user`